# What is the equivalent of `string` in C++

Tags: c++, string

In Python, there is a type named `string`, what is the exact equivalent of python's `string` in C++?

Comment: I would say `std::string` in `<string>`.

Comment: In Python 3, the default `str` supports unicode, which makes it quite different from `std::string`.

Comment: @VincentSavard `std::wstring` then?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius There is no built in support for Unicode in C++.  Even the higher width character strings are problematic.  If you need unicode in C++ it is best to use a library.

Comment: @VincentSavard: In what way does `std::string` not support unicode?

Comment: @NathanOliver [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Generic-Charset-Conversion.html#Generic-Charset-Conversion) does a pretty good job when character conversion is necessary.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Which reinforces my comment of best to use a library.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: `std::string("é").length() == 2`. There's no notion of encoding in a `std::string`, which makes it very different from Python's `str`.

Comment: @NathanOliver _"Which reinforces my comment"_ Of course, and it was meant so. As far I can see that library can be made working on serveral platforms.

Comment: @VincentSavard: Okay. I thought you were referring to the often repeated confusion that you need a wide character string to store unicode. Yeah, you'll need external functions in order to deal properly with code points. But you can of course (as you appear to know) store unicode strings in `std::string`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley And you can store images in `std::string`. But this is not *supported* – as Unicode is not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The equivalent is [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) or `std::wstring` declared in the `<string>` header file.

Though you should note that python has probably different intrinsic behavior about handling automatic conversions to UNICODE strings, as mentioned in [@Vincent Savard's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35779178/what-is-the-equivalent-of-string-in-c?noredirect=1#comment59230022_35779178).

To overcome these problems we use additional libraries in c++ like [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Generic-Charset-Conversion.html#Generic-Charset-Conversion). It's available for use on a broad number of platforms.

---

<sub>You should seriously note to do some better research before asking at Stack Overflow, or ask your question more clearly. `std::string` [is ubiquitous](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%2B%2B+string).</sub>

Answer (score 4):

You could either use `std::string` (see available interface here: [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/))
or use `char` array(or `const char*`) to represent a basic combination of characters that might function as a primitive string.

Comment: String is safer than char array, char array's not a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean the [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) family?

```
#include <string>

int main() {
  const std::string example = "test";
  std::string exclaim = example + "!";

  std::cout << exclaim << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```